# Uploading Bulk Recipients File Through DocuSign Rest API

Tags: c#, rest, httprequest, docusignapi

The DocuSign documentation gives this example for uploading a csv file through their rest api.  Below the image is the request object I'm trying but getting an error that says '***Value cannot be null. Parameter name: stream***'.  The example I posted doesn't actually try and send a csv.  When I tried attaching csv formatted text to the body of the request I got a different error that told me that the request body was invalid.

[image]

**REQUEST OBJECT**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the example request that DocuSign provides in the documentation is incorrect. Try changing the value of the **Content-Type** request header to **text/csv** (instead of **application/json**).

Here's an example of the full request (including verb/endpoint, headers, and body):

```
PUT https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/ACCOUNT_ID/envelopes/ENVELOPE_ID/recipients/RECIPIENT_ID/bulk_recipients

Content-Type: text/csv
Accept: application/json
Content-Disposition: file;filename=dsbulk.csv;fileExtension=.csv
X-Docusign-Authentication: {"Username":"USERNAME","Password":"PASSWORD","IntegratorKey":"INTEGRATOR_KEY"}

email,name
john.doe@test.com,John Doe
jane.doe@test.com,Jane Doe
```

This example request successfully updates/adds the specified bulk recipient info to the (draft) Envelope's *bulk recipient* signer.

Comment: I'll give this a shot in the morning and let you know how it goes.  Thanks!

Comment: Happy to help!  If this does resolve your issue, then please mark it as an 'accepted' answer so that others may benefit from it in the future.  Thanks!

Comment: This worked!  Although if anyone is planning to use the Docusign C# SDK, be warned that you have to download the source and modify ApiClient.PrepareRequest method to accept "text/csv"